# error Incorrect syntax near ','

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, ado.net

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=shashi-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=payroll;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("insert into Leave_trans values(" + txtempid.Text + ",'" + ddlleavetype.SelectedValue + "'," + txtallowedays.Text + "," + txtpendingleave.Text + ",'" + txtleavefrom.Text + "','" + txtleaveto.Text + "'," + txttotalleaves.Text + ")");
        com.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Leave data saved successfully')</script>");
        con.Close();
```

Comment: please give me the solution for my error....
my code is above mentioned

Comment: You don't have to comment asking for a solution...that's why you asked the question in the first place.  Also, I'm guessing one of your parameters is null or some unexpected value.  We can't help you without knowing what those values are.  Put a breakpoint in there and get the completed command string.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but you should **never** take user-input and use string concatenation to build an SQL query (please take some time to read about SQL injection e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) or [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)).

Instead of concatenating the full query, you should use `SqlParameter` instances as placeholders for your values, e.g:

```
var com = new SqlCommand(
    "insert into Leave_trans values(@empId, @leaveType, @allowedDays, ...)");
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@empId", txtempid.Text));
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@leaveType", ddlleavetype.SelectedValue));
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@allowedDays", txtalloweddays.Text));
...
```

BTW: the cause for your problem is that you are not correctly single-quoting your inputs inside the query (e.g. `txtempid.Text` is not in single quotes). Using SqlParameters will also solve that problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your query. You didn't provide us the data type of your database columns. But assuming from your query you are inserting some text from `TextBox` and one `DropDownList` selected item. From your `TextBox` text you will always get a string type value and for inserting `string` into your columns you should use single quotation `''` before and after on it. But on your query you didn't use any quotation for some of your value parameter. I made an assumption and made a query for you. try this updated one.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=shashi-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=payroll;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("insert into Leave_trans values(" + "'" + txtempid.Text + "'", "'" + ddlleavetype.SelectedValue + "'","'" + txtallowedays.Text + "'","'" + txtpendingleave.Text + "'", "'" + txtleavefrom.Text + "'","'" + txtleaveto.Text + "'", "'" + txttotalleaves.Text + "')");
        com.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Leave data saved successfully')</script>");
```

But i have some suggestion for you that is- you shouldn't use `string` as your table's primary key data type, it should be `int` type and another one is you should take `int` `id` of your selected item from your `DropDownList` not the text.